# Problem installing "fastai" on macOS 10.15

Tags: pip, fast-ai

When running `pip3 install fastai` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/9v/_09ftt2n0bv9sthtfh2j5gp80000gn/T/pip-install-zdk93g56/pynvx/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/9v/_09ftt2n0bv9sthtfh2j5gp80000gn/T/pip-install-zdk93g56/pynvx/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/9v/_09ftt2n0bv9sthtfh2j5gp80000gn/T/pip-record-7y_ev9f3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pynvx
```

Do you have any idea what the problem is?

There is another error saying I have to install CMake but I already installed it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is your problem (I'm a bit of a novice with this stuff), but I also was trying to install fastai with python 3.8 on macOS 10.15 and it failed on pynvx compilation.

I was able to get fastai to install, by ignoring its dependencies (and therefore pynvx), but was still able to successfully execute the libraries that required fastai. I did this:

```
pip install --no-deps fastai
```

and then ran my scripts. Can't say I understand why this works, but in the hopes that it does for you, I'm responding.